# docker: run python CMD startup script alongside ENTRYPOINT

Tags: python, docker, centos

I have an container based on CentOS, running gunicorn, and serving a flask app. I would like a startup script to run when it's first started, although I would like my entrypoint to remain my gunicorn call.

Dockerfile snippet

```
COPY startup.py /
ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:app"]
CMD /usr/bin/python3 /startup.py
```

I cannot get this to work with the shell style CMD instruction. The logs show CMD complaining that "Error: '/usr/bin/python3 /startup.py' doesn't exist", although both python3 and the startup.py file exist.

The reason I want this script to be run on startup is that I would like it to work against a volume that is being configured on run. I've tried many other configurations, but can't find the magic combo.

Comment: Put your `CMD` in an array like you have with your `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: I can't use the exec form if I already have an ENTRYPOINT defined. It overloads the CMD as params to the ENTRYPOINT.  See the crazy chart here (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact)

Comment: I was answering why your command was being treated as a whole string (with a space), rather than 2 commands. What command do you want your container to run?

Comment: If you're asking about the startup.py, it is taking pre-configured content files and unzipping them into the expected file structure that the flask app expects.

Comment: Can you exec into a container and confirmed that python3 exists? Can you post docker logs <container id> output?

Comment: Yes, I've verified that the path exists, and if I exec -it /bin/bash in, I can run the command without issue. Even if I make my CMD something simple like 'ls', it doesn't seem to find it if I have paired it with my ENTRYPOINT.